# Custom navigation bar title gets clipped after user leaves view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I need to extend my navigation bar height but since Apple made it very hard to change the navigation bar height in iOS 11 I decided I needed to use a custom view which extended the navigation bar without the user noticing.

I've created a custom view to add to the bottom of the navigation bar. I made it red just for the sake of making this question more clear. When the user leaves the view controller and then comes back, the title view custom view is "clipped" by the red view. Why?

[image]

[image]

I've tried to set `clipsToBounds` false on the custom title view, but that didn't help. How can I make sure the custom title view always stays on top of everything? Why is it being clipped and overlapped by the little red view (whose main purpose is to "extend" the navigation bar)?

Note: "Monthly Spending" label is part of the title view being clipped.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let customTitleView = CustomTitleView()

    let navigationBarExtensionView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAdditionalGradientView()
        navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView
    }

    internal func setupAdditionalGradientView() {
        view.addSubview(navigationBarExtensionView)
        navigationBarExtensionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarExtensionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarExtensionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarExtensionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18).isActive = true

        // Hide pixel shadow between nav bar and red bar
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Custom title view:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTitleView: UIView {

    let primaryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "$10,675.00"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 27.99, weight: .medium)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    let secondaryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Monthly Spending"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .medium)
        return label
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupStackView()
    }

    internal func setupStackView() {
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(primaryLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(secondaryLabel)
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good that you are showing code, but it is also necessary to say where that code goes. Remember, your goal is to allow someone else to _reproduce_ the issue exactly by following your instructions. If that's too hard, post an example project.

Comment: thanks @matt, updated question with complete code.

Comment: in the process of posting a sample project

Comment: This is much better, I can now sort of visualize what you're trying to do. It's illegal, of course, so I'm not surprised there's trouble. Let me ask this: what does the View Debugger tell you? Where is the Monthly Spending, when it is not visible?

Comment: I remember it said "Position and size are ambiguous for `CustomTitleView`", brb checking again

Comment: "Position and size are ambiguous" Okay, so that's your bug. I'm not saying you can fix the issue by fixing it, but you cannot proceed until you do fix it. It is idiotic to ignore a layout error from the View Debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 11, a custom bar button item view such as your `titleView` is sized from the inside out using constraints. Thus, you need constraints to size the view correctly. You are not providing any constraints, so the runtime doesn't know how to size the title view.

However, I would suggest that you just give up on the dubious idea of extending your UINavigationItem's custom view downward below the outside of the navigation bar, and instead, just show the words Monthly Spending in your view controller's view.

Comment: Wow that's actually genius. I never thought of showing the words in the VC.